# How to NOT show a modal again after a button is clicked/accepted/confirmed?

Tags: javascript, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal showing up that needs to be confirmed/accepted/clicked (button: #id_complete) in order to access the page. In order to activate the button the user needs to click two check boxes. The goal is: I want to have the modal to show up only until the #id_complete button IS NOT clicked/confirmed/accepted yet in the session. If the button is clicked/confirmed/accepted the modal shouldn't show up again. The cookie should be valid for 1 day. I'm using jquery-cookie-1.4.0

The below example only shows up on the first sites visit though, which is not the goal.

```
<button id="id_complete" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" disabled="disabled">I Accept!</button>

if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
     $('#myModal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
         });
     $.cookie('pop', '1');
 } 

 $('#accepted1,#accepted2').click(function () {
    if ($('#accepted1:checked,#accepted2:checked').length == 2)
        $('#id_complete').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $('#id_complete').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: Please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052232/i-am-getting-confused-about-the-backdrop-and-also-the-after-submit-close-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the modal function won't pause JavaScript execution which means the cookie will be set immediately.

To make the cookie expire after a day add an object with the `expires` property set 1.

Listen for the `hidden.bs.modal` or the `hidden` event on the modal depending on which version of bootstrap you have and then set the cookie:

```
// Bootstrap <2.3.2
if($.cookie('pop') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
    }).on('hidden', function(){
        $.cookie('pop', '1', {expires: 1});
    });
}
// Bootstrap 3
if($.cookie('pop') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $.cookie('pop', '1', {expires: 1});
    });
}
```

To answer the question in the comments:

To make it expire after the page session you can use window.sessionStorage object and store when the modal was last accepted:

```
var lastAccepted = parseInt(sessionStorage.lastAccepted);
// If lastAccepted isn't a number (because it doesn't exist or some other reason)
// or the last acceptance was more than a day ago 
if(isNaN(lastAccepted) || Date.now() - lastAccepted > 86400000) {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        sessionStorage.lastAccepted = Date.now();
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked! A minor additional wish ... can I have the cookie being valid for one day OR until the user closes the browser? Meaning, in addition everytime a new browser session starts the user needs to confirm the modal (independent from his cookie settings in the browser)?

Comment: And I have another issue ... I include the modal on multiple pages ... for a specific page the above is working ... yet if I call one of the other pages ... I need to click/confirm the modal again. How can I prevent this? Meaning, if I click the #id_complete button on whatever page, the cookie is valid for the other pages as well? Sorry for the additional questions

Comment: It should work on all pages. Could you include the code from the other pages in your question or start a new one? I added answers to your other question in my answer.

Comment: Awesome! ... with the window.sessionStorage solution it's working as hoped. I use the same code and modal on all other pages as well ... I just conditional include depending on the page ID ... I'm using the CMS TYPO3. But thanks a lot, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you set the cookie needs moving the click handler of the button.

In it's current position if the cookie is not found it will be created regardless of what the user is doing